# Understanding Java explanation

Tags: java

I'm doing an exercise where I need to implement a class and Ive a tough time understanding the explanation.

This is the explanation/exercise:

```
 * Adds all of the elements in the specified set, for which it is
 * possible, to this set.
 * post: all elements, for which it is possible, in the
 * specified set are added to this set.
 * @return true if this set changed as a result of the call
```

And this is the answer

```
public boolean addAll(SimpleSet<? extends E> s) {
    Iterator<? extends E> it = s.iterator();
    boolean changed = false;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        changed = add(it.next());
    }
    return changed;
}
```

This is what I tried doing myself, but I got a tough time wrapping my head around what Im supposed to do.

```
public boolean addAll(SimpleSet<? extends E> s){
        Iterator<? extends E> itr = s.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            add(itr.next());
        }
    return true;
}
```

Appreciative of any help possible,

Bobby.

Comment: What's confusing you? Your answer is not very different from the provided answer...

Comment: The provided answer is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, your answer is not very different to the provided answer, it will add all the elements given. What didn't you consider?

According to the definition of the method it should return a boolean indicating whether if the set changed as a result of the addition of elements. In your implementation, you just return true, which means that you are not considering when the elements your are trying to add already exist in the set. Although the given implementation only checks the last one which is not correct either.

Remember that by definition a Set cannot have repeated elements, so the boolean is there just to let the caller know if something actually changed.

Comment: If the set `s` is empty or the underlying `add` implementation returns `false` for all items, the method should return `false` as the set hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between your code and the provided answer is that yours unconditionally returns `true`, even if nothing has changed (in contrast to the stated requirement to return whether the set has changed). The provided answer is actually slightly flawed as well, in that it only returns whether the last object was accepted (i.e. it can return a false negative), that line should be `changed = changed || add(it.next());`.

Comment: I see, I think Im starting to understand that part now. But how can I test and see that the implementation worked? Like,
@Test
 public final void testAddAll() {
        ....
} Im running it in JUnit as a sidenote